# Database Connection Class PHP

Tags: php, database-connection

What is the best approach to creating a database class in PHP? I am using static. Should I use final too? If so, how and where? (I am using MySQLi instead of PDO)

```
class DB{

    public static $Link = null;

    public static function Link(){
        if(self::$Link == null){
            self::Connect();
        }
        return self::$Link;
    }

    public static function Connect(){
        if(self::$Link == null){
            $link = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
            if(!$link){
                echo 'Database Connection Failed';
            } else {
                self::$Link = $link;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Is there a somewhat standard practice for a Database Connection file?

Comment: If you're going to all of the work to create a class, you may as well inject the dependencies in the connect() function, or in a __construct() function so you can test it easily.   I would put the DB_HOST, etc. variables into a config array and pass that in to your method when you call it, so you can pass different arrays in for different environments or for testing.   Just something I see right off hand.  There's tons of examples out there.  You may look at how some of the major frameworks handle it, as those are usually well tested and well written.

Comment: @BrianH., I see that and thanks. Do you have a code to post that you liked the best in your programming practise? Just in case..

Comment: GitHub has several.  Here's one that works as well as any:  https://github.com/joshcam/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class